# Wrapping centered text in tabs

Tags: css, tabs, center, html-lists

I am looking for examples of css tabs with wrapping text, and the text being centered both vertically and horizontally. Something like this:

- |    This is     |                 |
- |  a very long   | Short title |
- |   tab title     |                 |

I'd like to know if this can be done with a simple ul-li-a node hierarchy or if I need to include additional layers (e.g. div or span). I need a cross-browser solution (IE 7+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari).

Comment: I found here many examples of centered tabs http://matthewjamestaylor.com/centered-menus/#.
Hope it helps you :)

Comment: @yurenaghm thx, but my need is to center the text inside the tabs, not center the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling tabs is not an easy task. For my specific need, I found out that using display:table on the ul element and display:table-cell on the li elements gave a satisfying result (although not supported by older browsers).

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the times when a table best serves your purpose. Here is the mark-up.

```
<table class="titles">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a long title.</td>
            <td>Short.</td>
            <td>This is an annoyingly long title.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .titles {
    margin: auto;
  }
  .titles td {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

With this simple mark-up I was able to achieve vertically and horizontally centered tabs.

Comment: and maybe display block on the anchor tag with a fixed width

Comment: +1 thx for the update. I posted an answer that allows to benefit from the table display properties while keeping the unordered list.